# Different version of Vim when launching from a Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, vim, scripting

When I run `vim --version` from a terminal, I see

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Aug 15 2018 18:27:33)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-280
Compiled by Homebrew
```

But when I run the same command within a Bash script, I see

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 19 2019 19:08:44)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283, 1365
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

The latter version is missing key features, like support for the system clipboard.

In both contexts, `whoami` returns the same username, and `which vim` return the same path.

How can I launch the Homebrew version from a script?

Comment: Check $PATH in your terminal and the script.

Comment: If you customize `PATH` in your `.profile`, make sure you export it so it's inherited by scripts.

Comment: run `type -a vim` from a terminal and from script, what do they give ?

Comment: `type -a vim` solved it - without realizing it, at some point I aliased `vim` to `mvim -v` ‍♂️

Thanks @Philippe - if you care to write up an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of situation often results from having different PATH settings between interactive shell and Bash script, or having an alias or function defined.

A quick way to finding out is to run `type -a vim`